# Eclipse Kepler not starting with specified vm

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

I've modified my eclipse.ini to:

```
-vm C:\Users\myuser\java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\javaw.exe
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130521-0416
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

In process explorer, i see that the exe is started with: `C:\Windows\System32\javaw.exe`

Why is it not picking up my specified vm?  In console, java -version from anywhere reflects the one i'd like to use, so my path is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The -vm switch needs to be on two lines. Try this:

```
-vm
C:\Users\myuser\java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\javaw.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Note the format of the -vm option - it is important to be exact:

The -vm option and its value (the path) must be on separate lines.
The value must be the full absolute or relative path to the Java executable, not just to the Java home directory.
The -vm option must occur before the -vmargs option, since everything after -vmargs is passed directly to the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse kepler also doesn't start when you have two versions of Java. One which is a higher version than the one specified in your Classpath and Path environmental variables.. So uninstall the higher version or change your classpath and path to the newer versions..Example I have Java 7u67 in my classpat hand path variables and some application has asked me to upgrade my java version to java 8u40..Then your kepler doesn't start..Uninstall java 8u40 or change the classpath and path..It works and it did for me..